# How do I resurrect companions / followers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've had a few companions who have died.

Is it possible to resurrect them? If not, where can they be hired from?

Comment: As of 14th of April, 2016 the accepted answer and every answer except for galacticninja's are **only** correct for the **console** versions. For the PC version there is a solution and it is stated by the aformentioned answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to resurrect lost companions. Any NPC who dies is dead forever.

Comment: In the mission where you retrieve the skeleton key, you have 2 companions who "pass out" when they have no health left and come back when their health regenerates. Is this the exeption to the rule?

Comment: @Coomie I've found that most NPCs (including villagers who foolishly would attack dragons) go into a wounded state when reduced to minimal health. From this state, only players can kill them. You wouldn't happen to be using some sort of friendly fire and accidentally kill your followers, would you?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I deal in fire - a lot. So there's a good chance. But hang on a second, I see villagers kill thieves all the time...

Comment: @Coomie most *unique* npcs. I've seen town guards die to dragons by the truckload.

Comment: @RavenDreamer you mean quest and essential NPCs.

Comment: Yes you can using cheats!

Answer (score 14):

There is No "legal" way to Do this.

But you can use the ressurect command in the console on PC. (see here [Skyrim Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29)  )

Answer (score 14):

#### Console commands (PC only)

If playing on the PC, use the console commands `prid <RefID>`  and `resurrect 1`. Your follower should go back to life after entering these commands correctly.

`prid` targets an entity - [your follower](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) in this case. Search for your follower's RefID here: [UESP.net Skyrim wiki 'Followers' article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers)

Another method to target instead of using `prid <refID>` is to open up the console and then click on an entity (like your follower's body), this will automatically do `prid <RefID>` for the clicked entity. This is useful if the body of your follower is visible and near you.

#### Teleporting lost or far follower

If your follower is still not near your vicinity or not visible after entering `resurrect 1`, try teleporting your follower to your location using the `moveto player` console command (after entering `prid <RefID>`).

`moveto player` moves that targeted entity near the vicinity of the player.

Your follower should now be near you after doing this.

If for another weird reason, your follower is still not near your vicinity or not visible after doing this, they may have been 'disabled' from the game (might happen with NPCs that are long dead), making your follower not appear in the game. Type `enable` in the console to remedy this. If your follower still isn't up, type `resurrect 1` again.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

#### Prevent your followers from getting killed in the first place

You can [make your follower "essential" (unkillable) as mentioned in an answer by Renan here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60169/4797) (PC-only console commands).

##### Mods

###### [UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul (PC original/Legendary Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037) / [(PC Special Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10681)

UFO will allow you to set your follower to be "essential" (unkillable).

###### [No More Dead Followers (Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3285503) / [(PS4)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3285861)

> Do you worry about casting a really powerful spell, going berserk with your two-handed weapon, or taking a risky bow shot because your your favorite follower gets in the way? Worry no more! This mod makes all followers (even animal followers) immortal, so they can't be killed--not even by you!

Comment: It's a shame that the most correct answer isn't the highest voted :/

Comment: Note: grab their loot beforehand. At least the one companion I resurrected in SSE came back with nothing but the default junk he started with.

Answer (score 5):

When a NPC goes to wounded mode other's will leave them alone, but they can still die if you are close to them, either they hit him trying to kill you or you kill him trying to kill them.

You can not make them come back, but staying away from them when they are in this modes help them live.

Comment: They will also die in wounded mode if they have been poisoned before.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-NPCs

The above link has Skyrim NPC base ID's.

This works for the PC. I have searched for the same problem then finally after trial and error of about 50+ codes I found the code for retrieving an NPC. If the NPC is dead you do NOT use Resurrect. The code doesn't seem to be working as intended at the moment. Instead you use:

player.placeatme "BaseID"

So an example of this would be if Alvor died and I needed to bring him back. This is what it would look like:

player.placeatme 00013475

You would enter that into console exactly how it is shown above. You enter console by pressing the tilda key (~). Hope this helps!

Comment: Chris YOU ARE MY HERO! A forest troll came into Dawnstar and killed half of the population. I was like no!!! But then I gladly found your answer, thanks so much!! T_T out of happiness

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` command: "*Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed.*" - http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console.  [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61255/4797).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can **prevent** a companion from dying by making them **immortal**, which means whenever their health drops to zero they will craw for a while before standing up. To do so type the following code in your console command:

`setessential #BaseID 1`

Replace `#BaseID` for the respective base id of your companion. It can easily be found in the wiki article of your follower. Example for [Lydia](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lydia):

`setessential A2C8E 1`

To reset to original condition use the same code placing '0' instead of '1'.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bring them back completely, but dead thrall works well