# My companion won't give me my items back in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been using my companion, Lydia, as a storage space until I can save up enough to get a house. However, when I try to retrieve certain armor from Lydia that she is NOT wearing and was not hers originally, the game says "can't take teammates' starting armor".
Even if it was actually hers, she doesn't need all 7 fur hides.
Why is this happening and how can I get it back?

Answer (score 3):

You don't NEED to kill her. The other option is to pickpocket your stuff back. To make it easier to pickpocket, gain the perk poisoned, pickpocket enough of her stuff to reverse pickpocket a paralysis potion, and pickpocket her while she gets back up. This will cause a 100% chance of pickpocketing all of her items even if there's a 0% chance of getting the item. This may be the only option left to get your stuff back without killing her.

Answer (score 1):

This happened probably because you told her to pick the items from the ground instead of giving to her in the traditional way (dialog --> I want to trade some stuff).

This method bypass the weight check (which is probably the reason you've used it) but also might bypass more important checks, so it might cause the item to become "default" - seen that in other answer here some time ago, can't find it though.

I fear the only solution is using console commands aka cheating.. just kill her, loot her corpse to retrieve all items then use the [answers here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/resurrecting-companions) to revive the poor woman.

Comment: Is that a pun: She will be poor once you robbed her that's for sure.

Comment: @Doomsknight wasn't a pun when I first wrote it but now that you said that.. :-)

Comment: To get around the ownership issue of items, pick up items first then drop them, you will be the owner. She can then pick them up and you can retrieve them from her with out them being 'stolen' from her.

Comment: @James it's not about "stolen" status - that's just annoying but not as "fatal" as items that can't be taken back.

Comment: oh ok that might explain it too thanks James. And I looks like Lydia is going to have to die Shadow Wizard. I am not a killer but she has enough item of mine that equal like at least 200 in value.

Comment: @Chill_LA hope you mean 2000 or even 20000 - 200 is just not enough to die for. ;)

Comment: One small comment, using the console commands to revive NPC's can mess up scripting. I would not use that myself.

Comment: Thanks @Ids, I have never used console commands myself actually.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the scripts are attached to each specific instance of an npc, and a revived npc has different instances. A tombstone/coffin is also spawned when a named npc dies in a city (or nearby a city). The coffin contains any items left on the body. I heard that causes problems. Not 100% sure btw.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is annoying, but ShadowWizard is correct - using an NPC to pick up apparel such as armour because, say, they've reached their carry limit but you really really really need that pair of dwarven boots causes them to assume the armour is theirs.

Lydia done this to me on one save, I made a load of dragonbone armour and dropped it because I couldn't be bothered to walk back home from the forge, and when I tried taking it from her, the game claimed it was hers. This being on the 360 version and my autosaves already being used up, I had to gut her and take the armour back.

Whatever, I didn't like Lydia anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can 'fire' her, then pickpocket her and steal your item back.