# In the game Skyrim, can I get Lydia back after accidentally killing her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resurrecting companions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/resurrecting-companions)

I killed Lydia by accident and now I want to know how to get her back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're playing on PC you can use the [console to resurrect](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#resurrect) her:

(If you know where her body lies, you can simply open the console, click on her and then use the resurrect command)
You can find more info at this [related question on how to resurrect companions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/resurrecting-companions) as [Jupotter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11089/jupotter) already said.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a PC but this is good info though.

Comment: @David maybe try going to the Hall of the Dead if you're on Xbox 360. She might be there.