# Follower disappeared after the "A Night To Remember" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Not long ago I did the 'A night to remember' quest. You will be teleported into another dimension then  when completed, you will be teleported back to the bar you found Sam.. But when I was there Jordis sword maiden was there with me to be my follower but when I was teleported she was not with me.. I tried to teleport her to me using commands and even going back to the same place but to no avail.. What do I do?

Comment: What console commands did you try?

Comment: Prid <reg. no.>                                              Moveto player @galacticninja 4

Answer (score 1):

If [Jordis the Sword-Maiden](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jordis_the_Sword-Maiden) does not appear (dead or alive) after entering `prid <refID>` and `moveto player`, she may have been 'disabled' from the game (might happen with NPCs that are long dead), making her not appear.

After entering `prid A2C95` (A2C95 is Jordis the Sword-Maiden's [refID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs)) and `moveto player`, enter `enable` in the console to remedy this. If she still isn't up, enter `resurrect 1`.

You could also make your follower essential (unkillable) using the [`setessential` console command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60169/4797) to prevent them from dying and being 'disabled' in the game.

More info on console commands here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console