# Mehrunes Razor Problem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

So I’m achievement hunting Skyrim, on my best save, I have 10/15 daedric artifacts needed for “Oblivion Walker”. So I don’t want to make a new build, but for the quest “Pieces of the Past”. I need Silus Vesuius alive, I kind of killed him right when I got the quest, thinking I could just take Mehrunes Razor for myself. Well I just realized (42 levels later) that you can’t do that. Is there anyway to get the Razor without starting from scratch?

Comment: Are you on PC? You could use the console to resurrect him.

Answer (score 2):

You have to finish [Pieces of the Past](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pieces_of_the_Past) in favor of Mehrunes Dagon to get Mehrunes' Razor through regular means. This means killing Silus at a certain part of the quest. If you're not playing on the PC, you'll have to load an earlier save before Silus was killed.

If playing on the PC, you can use the console command, `player.additem 240d2 1` to add Mehrunes' Razor to your inventory.

You can also try reviving Silus. I am unsure if this will allow the quest to start normally, though. Use the console commands `prid 240CE` and then `resurrect 1`. Silus should go back to life after entering those commands correctly. If this does not work in starting the quest you might have to try [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to advance / reset the quest to its correct stage. See the linked UESP wiki articles on console commands and quest stages of the Pieces of the Past quest for more info.

Comment: If corpse is gone, will it resurrect him nonetheless?

Comment: @AntiDrondert It should. See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86339/4797) for a more detailed explanation on how to revive dead NPCs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ask a question first, have you gone through the quest?

If no, then finish it. The demon-guy mehrun(e?) Makes you kill the scolar for you to fix it and have it.

If yes, reload. You can always load an earlier save file.

Comment: Well I only got the quest to find the parts for the Razor, I never actually got any further and never obtained any parts of the Razor. I just killed Silus after he gave me the quest. And I was at level 21 when this happened. I’m now level 63. I would rather not restart that far back.

Comment: It's not possible without silus, I'm sorry that you're a blood-thirsty bandit in Skyrim

Comment: I only got to point of getting the quest. The part where you must get the pieces for the Razor

Comment: Alright, it’s what a vampiric bandit assassin arch mage bard like me deserves